# How to make runOnUiThread synchronous

Tags: java, android

This method `onRemoteVideoStateChanged` is called asynchronously and `previous_uid` is a global variable and is set to 0.

```
@Override
public void onRemoteVideoStateChanged(final int uid, int state, int reason, int elapsed) {
    super.onRemoteVideoStateChanged(uid, state, reason, elapsed); 
     
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                if (previous_uid != uid) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "previous_uid = " + previous_uid + "  uid = "+ uid );
                    setupRemoteVideo(uid);
                    previous_uid = uid;
                }
            }
        }
    });            
}
```

I want that the method `setUpRemoteVideo` should be called only once with a unique uid.

But unexpectedly, it is called more than once and this is the logs:

> 2019-11-30 01:24:56.667 D/MY_LOGS: previous_uid = 0  uid = 656786280
>
> 2019-11-30 01:24:56.673 D/MY_LOGS: previous_uid = 0  uid = 656786280

Comment: Looks to me like you're synchronizing on the `Runnable` instance. And since you're always creating new `Runnable`s, that synchronization won't do you much good.

Comment: Other than initialization, is `previous_uid` accessed anywhere other than in the code you posted? If not, the issue @Michael mentioned aside, what's the purpose of the 'synchronized' block?

Comment: `previous_uid` is accessed no where else. The purpose of the synchronized block is to prevent the method call `setupRemoteVideo` from being called more than once for the same uid. @scg

Comment: Yes, you are right @Michael , but can you please provide a solution to synchronize this

Comment: Can you please check my answer and let me know if that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior that you are getting is actually correct. Because the `onRemoteVideoStateChanged` call is asynchronous and the situation might appear where this function is called from two background async threads at the same time and hence this explains the log that you posted. The key idea here is the `if(previous_uid != uid)` is not thread-safe.

You can create a `static synchronized` function that will return the true/false based on `previous_uid` and hence by making the function thread-safe, you can control your `setupRemoteVideo` function to be called for unique uid only. Let me try to give you an example.

```
public class UIDProvider {
    private static int uid = 0;

    public static synchronized boolean isDifferentThanStoredUid(int uid) {
        if (this.uid != uid) {
            this.uid = uid; // assign the new value here
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, from the `onRemoteVideoStateChanged` you can check the `uid` first before you do the `setupRemoteVideo` operation.

```
@Override
public void onRemoteVideoStateChanged(final int uid, int state, int reason, int elapsed) {
    super.onRemoteVideoStateChanged(uid, state, reason, elapsed); 

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // The check actually does not provide uniqueness. It justs check with the previous uid as far as I could understand. If you want uniqueness, then you might have to store all the values previously seen in a HashMap and look for the uid in the HashMap. 
            if (UIDProvider.isDifferentThanStoredUid(uid)) {
                Log.d("TAG", "previous_uid = " + previous_uid + "  uid = "+ uid );
                setupRemoteVideo(uid);
            }
        }
    });            
}
```

I think this should suffice.